# Symfony : set fields as null if not submitted in Form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

For this example, let's say I have an `Vehicle` Entity that can have the following values :

- `Type` : Bicycle, Motorbike, Car
- `Fuel` : `integer`

I create a new Vehicle object via a dynamic form. Please note that the field "fuel" will not be shown if the field `type` is set as "Bicycle".

I can successfully create this form thanks to Symfony documentation as some javascript :

```
<?php


$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $fields = null, array $options) {
    foreach ($fields as $field_id => $field_value) {
        if ($field_id == 'type') {
            if ($field_value && $field_value == 'bicycle') {
                $form->remove('gas');
            } elseif ($field_value && $field_value == 'motorbike') {
                $form->add('gas');
            } elseif ($field_value && $field_value == 'car') {
                $form->add('gas');
            }
        }
    }
};

$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier, $options) {
        $formModifier($event->getForm(), $event->getData(), $options);
    }
);
$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier, $options) {
        $vehicule = $event->getData();

        $formModifier($event->getForm(), array(
            'type' => $vehicule->getType(),
        ), $options);
    }
);

$builder->add('type', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array(
        'Bicycle'   => 'Bicycle',
        'Motorbike' => 'Motorbike',
        'Car'       => 'Car',
    ),
));
```

The data is then persisted with Doctrine.

However, there is a problem when I edit this form if the entity in the database already has a defined gas.

For example :

1. Entity in the database is a `Motorbike` with `gas = 10`.
2. I want to edit the form. The page show me two fields with Type and Gas. 3. I then choose "Bicycle". The field "Gas" disappear.
3. I submit the form. The attribute `Type` is updated and has now the value `Bicycle`. **But not the attribute `Gas`, that stays at `10`.**

How can I set the gas attribute as zero in this case ?

Comment: You've edited your question, but didn't say anything about my answer... Did it helped?

Answer (score 0):

Add a SUBMIT form event:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event){
    $data = $event->getData();

    if($data['type'] == 'Bicycle'){
        $data['gas'] = 0; //Note that in your entity, this field is named 'fuel'...
    }
    $event->setData($data); 
});
```